# Argument #1 ($values) must be of type array, null given Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel

I have 3 Models in My Laravel App like Employee , Salary and Title. Employee Model one to Many Relationship with both Salary and Title Models. Now I need update data using EmployeeController updateEmployee function using this function I need update some time all 3 tables tada also.
EmployeeController

```
public function updateEmployee(Request $request, $id) {
        $employee = Employee::find($id);
        $title = $employee->titles()->update($request->title);

        $salary = $employee->salaries()->update($request->salary);

        if(is_null($employee)) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Employee not found'], 404);
        }
        $employee->update($request->all());
        
        return response($employee, 200);
    
    }
```

and my api route is following

```
Route::put('updateEmployee/{id}','App\Http\Controllers\EmployeeController@updateEmployee');
```

Employee Model

```
public function titles(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Title::class, 'emp_no');
}

public function salaries(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Salary::class, 'emp_no');
}
```

Salary Model

```
public function employee(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class, 'emp_no');
}
```

Title Model

```
public function employee(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class, 'emp_no');
}
```

but when I try update using postman I got following error message
`TypeError: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::update(): Argument #1 ($values) must be of type array, null given, called in F:\2023\code\2023\api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\ForwardsCalls.php on line 23 in file F:\2023\code\2023\api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php on line 1009`

**
I really need update this 3 data tables when user need some update of these data tables. some time may be employees, some time employees and titles or some time all three tables with user need column or columns
**
how could I fix this problem?

Comment: Doesn’t really make sense to check `is_null($employee)` after you already tried to access the `$employee` twice before. And line 23 is what exactly?

Comment: What is it **exactly** you are trying to accomplish? Change all "Title" and "Salary" the "Employee" does currently have? Please add this information to your question and also include the body of your request, please.

Comment: @volkerschulz I really need update this 3 datatables when user need some update of these data tables. some time may be employees, some time employies and titles or some time all three tables with user need colum or columns

Comment: In Laravel we're dealing with models, not "tables". Your "Employee" model can have an unlimited number of "Salary" models and an unlimited number of "Title" models. So "I really need update" can literally mean a hundred different things. Change a property of "Employee", add a "Title" to "Employee", remove a "Title" from "Employee", change the property of a "Title" of "Employee", change all "Salary" of "Employee", .... just to name a few possibilities.

Comment: @volkerschulz could you give sample code as answer here. I am little bit not understand here

Answer (score 0):

The update needs array.

```
if ($model instanceof Emploee) {
    $emploee->titles()->update(['title' => $model->title]);
}
```

This is a mass update that will not trigger events.

Answer (score -2):

To resolve this issue, you should ensure that the $values variable is assigned an array **before** trying to use it. Here are some steps you can take to fix this problem:

```
$employee = Employee::findOrFail($id);
```

Before

```
$title = $employee->titles()->update($request->title);
```

Comment: same results here

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).